# Windows 7/Windows 7 two hdd dual boot - chkdsk runs after reboot/shutdown

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, chkdsk

I have a machine that came with Windows 7 64bit on one hard drive (ssd). I installed Windows 7 using the OEM recovery disks on a second drive (ssd) and I am currently dual booting using the BIOS boot menu. In both Windows 7 installs all hard drives are mounted and visible to each other, so that I can share files between them.

The problem I experience is that several times already (in a short period of time) chkdsk runs when I switch between the the OS saying that there are problems that need to repair, which it does and then it boots fine. However, the last time I booted into Windows A it said that there is a problem with A's partition and it can't run chkdsk. I booted into Windows B, which ran chkdisk automatically and fixed A's partition, but A wouldn't load due to a blue screen. I ended up using some OEM repair tool which showed up in the Windows A boot menu and that fixed it.

My question is:

Is my setup wrong? Why am I seeing those chkdsk problems? One of my friends suggested that Windows B is overwriting Windows A's volume identifier which is causing it to get confused and visa-versa, but I can't find anything useful on the Internet?

P.S: I have ran numerous HDD diagnostic tools on both HDDs and they show no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the issue is with the OS and the SSD. In fact old tools made for spindle type drives like chkdsk and defrag should not ever be used on an SSD as it is unnecessary and in some cases can degrade the SSD. Make sure trim is enabled and that Windows 7 knows what it has is an SSD. You may want to check your BIOS settings as well.